# overwriting div contents in a file and removing old contents completely from file

Tags: php, dom

the below code successfully removes the child div from the file (no problem) which is what i am looking for, but what i also want, is to remove the codes that make the child div in the first place so that the file remains small, because when i do view source for the file, i see the codes that makes the child div and then the code below removing it, making the file large every time I remove and add divs. If what i am tryin to achieve is possible, please also let me know if i can remove or rather OVERWRITE single html elements in a file .

```
 $myfile = fopen("../userfolders/$email/$ongrassdb/$pagenameselected.php", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
 $txt = '<script>
 var parent = document.getElementById("wrapper");
 var child = document.getElementById("rock");
 parent.removeChild(child);
 </script>';
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code solved it for me, it overwrites the content completely

```
$dir = "path";
$line = 'texttochange';
$line2 = 'towhatever';
$contents = file_get_contents($dir);
$contents = str_replace($line, $line2, $contents);
file_put_contents($dir, $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

The file does not get smaller in terms of network load. If you are in control of the source anyway (php), then why not strip it completely, without the javascript overhead?

Try http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

*[Edit]*
If you would like to find a specific elemt by id, use the method http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Comment: ,i am getting the ids with js dynamically,  i wanna sort of delete lines from the file, divs to be specific,

Comment: or is it possible to delete a child div from a file with just php and no js ?

Comment: If you can get the ids with js, then you can with php. Unless the ids are generated after pageload. In that case I would suggest to write a seperate javascript file and load it.